# C# - Connect to Outlook 2010 Mailbox to take Xls Files

Tags: c#, ssis, outlook

I had a a c# script that connects to an OFFICE 365 mailbox and then take any emails with an xls file and puts it in a shared folder. Problem is now the OFFICE 365 mailbox has becomes an Outlook 2010 on premises mailbox, and the script has stopped working.

My questions is what Service URL and service credentials do I use, Is it the same syntax or do I need a new way of connecting in the script ?

OLD script

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ST_0710846949654fbd84606ec3011bd081.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    /*
        The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
        To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
        and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.

        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */


        public void Main()
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;



            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxreturns@xxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk", "PasswordXXXXXXXXX", "mail.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk");
            service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.xxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/owa");

            // Variable population
            string FileName1 = null;
            string attSaveLocation = Dts.Variables["User::attSaveLocation"].Value.ToString();
            string destfold = Dts.Variables["User::destFolder"].Value.ToString();
            string emailFrom = Dts.Variables["User::emailFrom"].Value.ToString();
            string filetype = Dts.Variables["User::filetype"].Value.ToString();

            //find items in the email folder
            FindItemsResults<Item> foundItems =
            service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(600)); //can limit how many results are pulled

            foreach (Item item in foundItems)
            {
                string tmpitemid;
                string processed = null;
                tmpitemid = item.Id.ToString();
                if (item is EmailMessage)
                {
                    // Bind to an existing message item, requesting its Id property (using the tmpitemid) plus its attachments collection.
                    EmailMessage foundEmail = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(tmpitemid), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
                    EmailMessage foundEmail2 = (EmailMessage)item;
                    FindFoldersResults findResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));

                    //get the from e-mail address for exchange addresses
                    string fromaddress = null;
                    NameResolutionCollection nd = service.ResolveName(foundEmail2.From.Address);
                    foreach (NameResolution nm in nd)
                    {
                        if (nm.Mailbox.RoutingType == "SMTP")
                        {
                            fromaddress = nm.Mailbox.Address.ToLower();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fromaddress = foundEmail2.From.Address.ToString().ToLower();
                        }
                    }
                    //for other addresses
                    if (fromaddress == null)
                    {
                        fromaddress = foundEmail2.From.Address.ToString().ToLower();
                    }
                    //if the email address is like the parameter
                    if (fromaddress.Contains(emailFrom))
                    {
                        //process attachments
                        foreach (Attachment attachment in foundEmail.Attachments)
                        {
                            if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                            {
                                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
                                FileName1 = attSaveLocation + fileAttachment.Name;
                                if (fileAttachment.Name.Contains(filetype))
                                {
                                    fileAttachment.Load(FileName1);
                                    processed = "Y";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (processed == "Y")
                        {
                            // Get all the folders in the message's root folder.
                            Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
                            rootfolder.Load();
                            foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100)))
                            {
                                if (folder.DisplayName == destfold)
                                {
                                   foundEmail2.Move(folder.Id);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Office 365 is primarily web based, office 2010 was not. OWA is exchange not outlook.. OWA was not necessarily required to be setup before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for Outlook 2010, but perhaps this link can help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations